# Correctly using port.emit & port.on between main.js and a script attached to a tab

Tags: javascript, firefox, tabs, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm trying to make a function in this extension that will open a tab with a given url and run a script on that tab with a given filename. The function mostly works except that I am unable to communicate between the main script and the script I ran on the new tab (I used .attach for this). I know the communication isn't working because *it hasn't been printing "Contact successful, over" in the console* which should be triggered via one of the .port functions which is currently commented out.

I have been going over the Mozilla tutorials for hours now. I'm pretty sure I screwed up something simple, but I can't find a good example in the tutorial that uses tabs, .port functions, and external scripts.

Addon works by:
(starting with Main)

1. Adding a button to the toolbar that opens a panel (`DeltaLogPanel`)
2. This panel has a button that triggers some user input processing (get-text.js) and our function of interest (Main.js>TryFA)
3. This function should open a new tab with the given url
4. Upon the loading of this tab, the function should also have a stored script (`FAmeddle`) run on this tab
5. The function needs to facilitate (or at least trigger) communication between the tab's script and the main script. This includes passing variables

These scripts are a severely cut down version of my addon, however the addon works and retains the main problem of doing the fifth step.

**Main.js**

```
var data = require("sdk/self").data;
var journal_entry = require("sdk/panel").Panel({
    contentURL: data.url("DeltaLogPanel.html"),
    contentScriptFile: data.url("get-text.js")
});
require("sdk/ui/button/action").ActionButton({
    id: "show-panel",
    label: "Show Panel",
    icon: {
        "16": "./icon-16.png",
        "32": "./icon-32.png",
        "64": "./icon-64.png"
    },
    onClick: handleClick
});
function handleClick(state) {
    journal_entry.show();
}
journal_entry.on("show", function() {
    journal_entry.port.emit("show");
});

function ShoutOut(x) {
    console.log(x);
}

//this should open up a new tab and run a script on it
function TryFA(URL, SCRIPT) {

    var tabs = require("sdk/tabs");
    tabs.open({
        url: URL,
        onReady: function onReady(tab) {
            console.log("the open triggered");
            tab.attach({
                contentScriptFile: data.url(SCRIPT)
            });
            /* tab.port.on("WeReadYouLoudAndClear",ShoutOut(signal)); */
            //self.port tabs.port and tab.port don't work here
        }
    });
}
/* self.port.on("WeReadYouLoudAndClear",ShoutOut(signal)); */
//tabs.port tab.port and self.port really screw things up here

//This is what the panel button triggered
journal_entry.port.on("cargo-shipping", function (cargo) {
    journal_entry.hide();
    TryFA("http://www.reddit.com/","FAmeddle.js");
});
```

**DeltaLogPanel.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <style>
            #MainPanel 
            {
                width: 180px;
                height:180px;
                background-color: #ACA1A1;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body id="MainPanel">
        <div id="simpleOptions">
            <textarea id="titleBox" placeholder="Title" rows="1"></textarea>
            <button type="button" id="publishButton">Publish</button>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**get-text.js**

```
//This script was user for processing and passing along user input. It worked perfectly,
//so there's not much I need to show you here
var titleArea = document.getElementById("titleBox");
var finalButton = document.getElementById("publishButton");

//this defines the cargo on the button press then ships it.
finalButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    // Remove the newline.
    var cargo = {
        //This is the user input passed from the panel going to main
        title: ""
    };
    cargo.title = titleArea.value.replace(/[\n\r]/g, '');
    self.port.emit("cargo-shipping", cargo);
    //next we reset everything Note, this doesn't erase local cargo, just the text on the panel
}, false);

self.port.on("show", function onShow() {
  titleArea.focus();
});
```

**FAmeddle.js**

```
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("sr-header-area");
    x.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    var signal = "Contact successful, over";
    console.log("the function ran at least");
    self.port.emit("WeReadYouLoudAndClear", signal);
}
console.log("Shout out from the extra script!");
myFunction();
```

**These are my questions:**

1. Is there a better way to run a script on a newly opened tab like this?
2. How can I make `.port` and `.o`n work in this? (If there is a better way to communicate between main.js and the new page script, explain that instead)
3. [optional query] I'm going to be running this overall function several times. So at least six different scripts for new tabs will be loaded one by one. How do I prevent this from causing performance issues?

EDIT: Solution
In Main
Instead of this:

```
function TryFA(URL, SCRIPT) {
    var tabs = require("sdk/tabs");
    tabs.open({
        url: URL,
        onReady: function onReady(tab) {
            console.log("the open triggered");
            tab.attach({
                contentScriptFile: data.url(SCRIPT)
            });
            tab.port.on("WeReadYouLoudAndClear",ShoutOut(signal));
            //This ShoutOut function doesn't work for a completely separate reason
        }
    });
}
```

use this:

```
function TryFA(URL, SCRIPT) {
    var tabs = require("sdk/tabs");
    tabs.open({
        url: URL,
        onReady: function onReady(tab) {
            console.log("the open triggered");
            worker = tab.attach({
                contentScriptFile: data.url(SCRIPT)
                });
        worker.port.on("WeReadYouLoudAndClear",function(signal) {
        console.log(signal);
        worker.port.emit("Connection stable", Backback);
        });
        }
    });
}
```

Edit 2: `Backback` is a message variable sent from another addon code. It's not that important.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>    tab.attach({
>        contentScriptFile: data.url(SCRIPT)
>    });
>    /* tab.port.on("WeReadYouLoudAndClear",ShoutOut(signal)); */
>    //self.port tabs.port and tab.port don't work here
> ```

`tab.attach()` [returns a worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/tabs#attach%28options%29), which in turn has a [port](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/content_worker). The tab itself does not have a port, as you noted in your comment.

Alternatively `attach` also accepts a callback as `onMessage` option.

MDN also has [code examples](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts/port#port) for worker and addon-main port usage.

Comment: 1. Where should this communication take place in the script? It's currently the last thing triggered by "onReady: {}"

2. Am I calling port on the right object? I tried self, tabs, and tab.

3. Can you give me a sample of what the code in TryFA should look like?

Comment: I think you're asking too many questions at once. I'm just trying to solve the most glaring issue. "what's the best way to do X" is a separate issue from "why does Y not work".

Comment: Could you give me an example code of **how** to use the port function of this tab's worker?